# SQL: select max(A), B but don't want to group by or aggregate B

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

If I have a house with multiple rooms, but I want the color of the most recently created, I would say:

```
select house.house_id, house.street_name, max(room.create_date), room.color
from house, room
where house.house_id = room.house_id
and house.house_id = 5
group by house.house_id, house.street_name
```

But I get the error:

> Column 'room.color' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I say max(room.color), then sure, it will give me the max(color) along with the max(create_date), but I want the COLOR OF THE ROOM WITH THE MAX CREATE DATE.

*just added the street_name because I do need to do the join, was just trying to simplify the query to clarify the question..*

Comment: Check `max(column) over (partition by column order by column)` via google

Comment: Which database do you really use? I suppose not ALL of them.

Comment: Please, do not spam tags. MySQL <> Oracle <> SQL Server. I've removed all the tags, please add only one of your real DBMS

Comment: Also consider ANSI join via `JOIN` clause instead of simple `where` predicate. It is much more readable and easy to debug

Comment: I'm really on SQLServer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding this to work for any number of houses (rather than only working for exactly one house)...

```
SELECT
  house.*,
  room.*
FROM
  house
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (1) room.create_date, room.color
    FROM room
   WHERE house.house_id = room.house_id
ORDER BY room.create_date DESC
)
  AS room
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you would write this as:

```
select r.house_id, r.create_date, r..color
from room r
where r.house_id = 5
order by r.create_date desc
offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that the `house` table is not needed.  If you did need columns from it, then you would use `join`/`on` syntax.

Not all databases support the standard `offset`/`fetch` clause.  You might need to use `limit`, `select top` or something else depending on your database.

The above works in SQL Server, but is probably more commonly written as:

```
select top (1) r.house_id, r.create_date, r..color
from room r
where r.house_id = 5
order by r.create_date desc;
```

Comment: But why `offset 1`? I didn't get the idea behind this.

Comment: @astentx . . . I don't know either.  I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

One option is `WITH TIES` and also best to use the explicit `JOIN`

If you want to see ties, change `row_number()` to `dense_rank()`

```
select top 1 with ties
       house.house_id
      ,room.create_date
      , room.color
from house
join room  on house.house_id = room.house_id
Where house.house_id = 5
Order by row_number() over (partition by house.house_ID order by room.create_date desc)
```

Comment: Doesn't `WITH TIES` work with `ORDER BY somedate DESC` then?

Comment: @MatBailie Sure does, but now the Where house_id=5 is optional  ... which I did not express  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could order by create_date and then select top 1:

```
select top 1 house.house_id, room.create_date, room.color
from house, room
where house.house_id = room.house_id
and house.house_id = 5
order by room.create_date desc
```